# Group multiple query results in one column

Tags: sql-server-2008, drop-down-menu

Is it possible to do a Query with a subquery and to get the subquery results inside one column (`DropDownList style`) of the first query ?

```
Select Name, Year, (Select SchoolId from Schools) from SchoolRecords

Output :

--------------------------      List would be a DropDownList and if I open it I would get
| Name | Year | SchoolId |      the results of my subquery like so :
|      |      |          | 
--------------------------      ------------------
| Jim  | 2011 | List  || |      |             || |
|      |      |       \/ |      |             \/ |
--------------------------      ------------------
| Tom  | 2012 | List  || |      |    012312324   |
|      |      |       \/ |      |    123245465   |
--------------------------      |    456547787   | 
                                ------------------
```

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand, do you want the items in a comma separated list?  Can you add some sample data for each table?

Comment: @bluefeet anything would do.. as long as there are many values in a single cell. Comma separated or dropdownlist (altough I doubt it can be done that way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to create a drop-down of values in SQL. But if you just want the list of schools in the schools column, then you can use `FOR XML PATH` to get the list:

```
Select Name, 
  Year, 
  STUFF((SELECT distinct ', ' + cast(s.SchoolId as varchar(10))
         from Schools s
         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
         ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,2,'') schools
from SchoolRecords
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/552d3/2)

Then if you had a table that associated each `SchoolRecords` with a specific `school`, then you could display only the schools associated with each user:

```
Select Name, 
  Year, 
  STUFF((SELECT distinct ', ' + cast(s.SchoolId as varchar(10))
         from Schools s
         inner join record_school rs
           on rs.schoolid = s.schoolid
         where r.id = rs.id
         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
         ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,2,'') schools
from SchoolRecords r;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/82be9/1)